# Loading a *.dll from a *.lib and using this lib in generating an *exe afterwards: Is it possible?

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries, exe

I want to use the functionality of a 3rd party dll into a lib I create.
Something like this:

```
m_hLib = LoadLibrary(L"Bla.dll");
```

and the using this with:

```
void* fnBla = ::GetProcAddress(m_hLib , "MethodFromBla");
```

to use some stuff from the respective method.

Now my question would be: could I build the lib like this and then use its functions from an exe?

Comment: Of course, just don't forget to deploy Bla.dll together with your .exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Problems at all . exe gets statically linked to the lib file . That means lib code becomes part of exe code . Now the exe code is loading the dll dynamically :)

Comment: There is no real code in the .lib, just fixup information about .dll exports. The code lives in the .dll.

Comment: .lib can contain code also :) . you are talking about a condition when the .lib file is used by the linker for the symbols exposed by dll . This is not the case here the user has written a piece of code which loads a dll at runtime and calls the function which is compiled in to a lib .

Comment: Yes, a lib can contain code, but it's pretty much always the case that the .lib used to statically link a .dll doesn't contain code that will be shared, but instead contains fixup information for the linker/loader to interact with the .dll

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is dynamic (or runtime) linking, ie you explicitly load the .dll and resolve the functions via `GetProcAddress`. If you're doing this then you don't need a .lib file.

A .lib file is only necessary if you want to statically link against the .dll at compile time. The linker takes the .lib file and resolves the references in your program against the functions information in the .lib. Therefore, if you don't plan to link to the .dll at compile time you won't need a .lib. You just need to make sure that the .dll (Bla.dll in your case) it  released alongside your application.

Comment: I think that OP wants to put the `LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress` code into a static lib and link the exe with that lib. Hence the "Of course" comment from @Adriano